# Show native push notification when app is open?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

Is there a way to show the native notification (iOS) dialog when a push notification has been received and the app is open ? More specifically I mean the black dialog that appears at the top of the screen that can be swiped up to close.

I am using https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin this plugin to get push notification..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to build it yourself and catch the push notification in the app delegate.

Comment: can u elaborate little more ... @TheEye

Comment: Simulator menu -> Window -> Scale -> 100%. If it is not at 100%, the screen is interpolated, so if you have 1 pixel lines they might not show on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

in that method use this condition:

```
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {

// Show Notification using custom view/alert

}
```